# Bypass "table or view does not exist" in package compilation

Tags: oracle, compilation, package, synonym

There are two schemas in a Oracle database.

`MYSCHEMA` that is controlled by me.

`OTHERSCHEMA` that is not controlled by me.

I just know I can get result from `select * from OTHERSCHEMA.OTHEROBJECT`. However, `OTHEROBJECT` is a **synonym**.

In my package, I have a statement like

```
insert into MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE(COL1) select COL1 from OTHERSCHEMA.OTHEROBJECT;
```

But it gave me `Table or view does not exist.`

How can I solve or bypass this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You are logged in to `MYSCHEMA` and run `select * from OTHERSCHEMA.OTHEROBJECT` and it works? Your package is compiled under `MYSCHEMA`? Have you tried running the insert statement outside of the package as a standalone statement - does that work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you received the privilege to select from `otherschema.otherobject` by means of a *role* as opposted to a direct grant (such as `grant all on otherschema.otherobject to myschema`). If this is the case, the privileges within this role will not be used to determine what rights you have within a PL/SQL block.

See also [How Roles Work in PL/SQL Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#autoId16) (Oracle Docu, where it says under **Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights**:

> All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block (stored procedure, function, or trigger) that executes with definer's rights. Roles are not used for privilege checking and you cannot set roles within a definer's rights procedure.)