# ORACLE11g, table or view does not exist while creating procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, procedure

There're two schema in db, I create a materialized view -- 'MV1' and grant it successfully，selecting from it in other schema is ok.

```
GRANT select ON schemaA.MV_CA_REVENU_MS_GEO TO read;
/
GRANT select ON schemaA.MV_CA_REVENU_MS_GEO TO write;
/
GRANT update ON schemaA.MV_CA_REVENU_MS_GEO TO write;
/
```

But while compiling the procedure, there's error message says 'table or view does not exist' for 'MV1'. The procedure code is:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE                     SP_NAME (args ... ) is
  .
  .
begin
    INSERT INTO tableName(
        .
        .
      ) SELECT ...
          FROM (SELECT ...
                  FROM MV1  -- **schemaA.MV1 doesn't work either** 
                 WHERE 
end SP_NAME;
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON schemaB.SP_NAME TO read;
GRANT DEBUG ON schemaB.SP_NAME TO read;
GRANT EXECUTE ON schemaB.SP_NAME TO write;
GRANT DEBUG ON schemaB.SP_NAME TO write;
/
CREATE or replace PUBLIC SYNONYM SP_NAME FOR schemaB.SP_NAME;
/
```

I try to add schemaA in front of MV1, it doesn't work. Is there any other step should I take a check?

Comment: I assume this is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599393/bypass-table-or-view-does-not-exist-in-package-compilation . So just check solution there. You need to use direct grants instead of roles.

Comment: So be it! Sorry for my oversight and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are "read" and "write" schema names or role names? Permissions in Oracle granted indirectly via roles are not available when compiling stored procedures, functions, and packages